# Can Eclipse's Java Format/Cleanup Operations Change Runtime Behavior?

Tags: java, eclipse, code-formatting, code-cleanup

I am about to cleanup/format over 700 Java files in my work using Eclipse's format and cleanup operations. My bosses are worried that all of this cleanup/formatting may cause changes in runtime behavior.

As far as I am aware the only cleanup/format preference that may change runtime behavior is "Clean Up/Code Organizing/Members/Sort Members/Sort all members" and Eclipse warns you about this.

So my question is aside from the preference mentioned above are all other Eclipse cleanup and format preferences safe? Or has anyone ever come across a situation where performing cleanup/format has changed their program's runtime behavior?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Do not do that. Not because it can change runtime behaviour, but because with reformatting you will loose history of changes in VCS(Version control system).

Comment: I should have mentioned. We understand the problems with diff/compare operations that this can cause. However we are just about to change to a new VCS in our work, so we will have no history to lose. There is still the problem if people want to do a manual diff/compare with a file across the two VCSs but the state that the code is in at the minute we are prepared to take that hit. Thanks.

Comment: If these changes break anything, it's because you have dependencies on undocumented behavior.

Having said that... Sorting the members, in my experience, is more likely to remove useful information (eg, meaningful grouping of functions) than to improve the code. Unless you have a Good Reason for doing so, I wouldn't. Eclipse can display a sorted list of the members without having to actually sort the code.

Comment: Hey keshlam. Yes I am going to stay away from sorting altogether. It seems of little use to me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Although unlikely it is possible that changing the order of a field declaration or initializer could cause changes at runtime. Take this example:

```
public class MyClass {
    private static int I;
    private static int J = I + 1;

    static {
        I = 2;
    }
 }
```

If you reorder the declarations like this the value of J will end up getting initialized to 3 instead of 1.

```
public class MyClass {
    private static int I;

    static {
        I = 2;
    }

    private static int J = I + 1;
 }
```

Comment: Hey Matt. Useful example of how reordering can alter the behavior. I am going to stay away from any sort of reodering in the format/cleanup, aside from reordering import statements. I am wondering if any of the other format/cleanup preferences can cause issues. Such as removing unused private/local variables, adding braces around all if/for/else/while statements, putting all expressions in parenthesis, removing unnecessary casts etc. Thanks

Comment: The vast majority of reordering declarations will not have any impact on semantics or runtime behavior. For example reordering method declarations has no such side effect. I wouldn't be terribly worried about it in general but it is something you need to consider.